# Find $\iint_A \sqrt[4]{\sqrt[4]{x-2}+\sqrt[4]{y-3}}dxdy $ if $A$ is bounded by :$\ \sqrt[4]{\sqrt[4]{x-2}+\sqrt[4]{y-3}}=1;x=2;y=3$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find $$\iint_A \sqrt[4]{\sqrt[4]{x-2}+\sqrt[4]{y-3}}dxdy $$ if $A$ is bounded by the functions: $$\ \sqrt[4]{\sqrt[4]{x-2}+\sqrt[4]{y-3}}=1;x=2;y=3$$ I was thinking conditional extremums where $x=z=0$ (for $y$ limits in the integral) and when integrating over $x$ just set the limits $x\geq 0$ and the upper limit as the larger function that bounds the set in terms of $x$ equals..  I tried this:$$\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\int_{0}^{(1-\sqrt[4]{y-3})^4+2}\sqrt[4]{\sqrt[4]{x-2}+\sqrt[4]{y-3}}dxdy$$ where $y_1, y_2$ are the conditional extremums of the function with plane xOz. $x\geq0,y\geq 0, z\geq 0.$ Then finding the acual integral would seem easy..

Comment: Find... **what** ? You're giving an equality between a double integral and a number, so what is there to find? You mention later "the limits", so are you asking how to find the limits of the integral s.t. that it equals one?

Comment: i mean integrate this function over the set A

Comment: The set A as it stands is just a number

Comment: when i mention limits i just mean say miny=y1 miny=y2 are the maximum values of y in set A which could be useful when integrating in respect to y.

Comment: I really don't understand what $A$ is. Why is it a set of equations instead of a subset of the plane ?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic But the result of the integral is already given by you: it is one ! Besides this, as the other comment says, as you defined it, the set $\;A\;$ contains only one number, namely $$\sqrt[4]{\sqrt[4]{2-2}+\sqrt[4]{3-3}}=\sqrt[4]{0}=0$$

Comment: A is actually the region bounded by these functions, sorry..